# referring to a div from outside class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onscroll

I have a div which is scrollable and i want to refer that div from outside my class. For example

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById('scrollDiv');

class Test extends React.Component{

  listenScrollEvent = (e) => {
    console.log("myDiv returns undefined",myDiv);
  };

  render(){
   return (
    <div id="scrollDiv" onScroll={this.listenScrollEvent.bind(this)}></div>
  )
  }
}
```

Here inside `listenScrollEvent` i want to access `myDiv` which is referred to div with id `scrollDiv`. But i'm getting a `undefined` value in my console log. I can use `const myDiv = document.getElementById('scrollDiv');` inside my `listenScrollEvent` method but then every time i scroll, referring to div happens.

Comment: I think refs are what you searching for: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: never use dom selectors in react like `getElementById`. its bad practice, use ref's

Answer (score 1):

You can access an element by using refs in React like this -

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = null;
  }
  listenScrollEvent = () => {
    console.log(this.myRef.getBoundingClientRect().top);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        ref={my => (this.myRef = my)}
        id="scrollDiv"
        onScroll={this.listenScrollEvent}
      >
        Click Me!
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

More on refs - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Thanks. But i'm trying to get getBoundingClientRect().top value of the div. When scrolling the value does not change.

Comment: I have created a code sandbox for the same - https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-voice-326o0 . Can you check if this helps?

Comment: Oh my mistake. It should be done for a onScroll , not onClick. Everytime i scroll the value does not get update in the console.log. I have updated my code in the question now.

Comment: I just gave one example where i used onClick. But no matter what the event is you should be able to access the element with `this.myref`